# Powershell WPF RichTextBox Surpress Backspace not working

Tags: wpf, powershell, keypress, keyup

I am currently working on a little automation services for some company processes. I have a small GUI currently to edit JSON files and I am capturing and monitoring key input, surpressing it when outside of editable JSON syntax. Backspace however is giving me a bit of trouble, I have already read that it is not captured by KeyDown but rather only by KeyUp. This is indeed the case and KeyUp fires when pressing it, however no matter what I do i can not get it to ignore the input. I have both set .Handled to $true and .SurpressKeyPress, but neither are having any effect. I have checked the values at the end of the handler and they are correct. Any help would be appreciated!

```
$richTextBox1_KeyPress=[System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler]{
    #Write-Host ($_ | Format-List | Out-String)
    if($global:canType -eq $false) {
        $_.Handled = $true
    }
}

$richTextBox1_KeyUp = {
    if($global:canType -eq $false) {
        $_.Handled = $true
        $_.SuppressKeyPress = $true
    }
    Write-Host ($_ | Format-List | Out-String)
}
```

- Maybe someone can explain to me aswell why I had to cast the KeyPress event to [System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler] in order to have the Handled variable inside the pipe. Oterwise there was only the keyCode to read and no other properties

- Edit
  Scriptblock Assignment

  ```
    $richTextBox1.Location = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]0,[System.Int32]0))
    $richTextBox1.Name = [System.String]'richTextBox1'
    $richTextBox1.Size = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]510,[System.Int32]182))
    $richTextBox1.TabIndex = [System.Int32]0
    $richTextBox1.Text = [System.String]''
    $richTextBox1.add_SelectionChanged($richTextBox1_SelectionChanged)
    $richTextBox1.add_KeyPress($richTextBox1_KeyPress)
    $richTextBox1.add_KeyUp($richTextBox1_KeyUp)
    $richTextBox1.add_MouseUp($richTextBox1_MouseUp)
  ```

Comment: Try using `$this.SuppressKeyPress` instead of `$_` in the KeyUp scriptblock. Also, it would help if you show us how you add these scriptblocks to the RichTextBox. Normally this is done with `$richTextBox1.Add_KeyUp({...})`.

Comment: Hello again @Theo :) I am using Powershell Pro Tools so its auto generated, doubt there is an error there but I added it to my question

Comment: Aha, thanks for showing that. Did you try with `$this` instead of `$_`? Inside the handler,  `$this` is shorthand for the actual control, so in this case `$richTextBox1`

Comment: @Theo I tried it just now and indeed $this is a ref to $richTextBox1. However I fail to see what I could access here that would help me as obviously Handled and SurpressKeyPress are not properties of $richTextBox1

Comment: I believe `SuppressKeyPress` is only valid in the `KeyDown` event. The order of events is KeyDown-KeyPress-KeyUp so if you want to suppress the KeyPress you need to use the event before that.

Comment: @Theo you dont disappoint ;)

Answer (score 1):

So as Theo pointed out it is better to use KeyDown as the eventhandler.
However there is a caviat I have encountered. I do not know why but setting `$_.Handled = $true` works 95% of the time, however there seems to be a condition in which a-z 1-9 is still passed through and is only canceled if you also set `$_.SuppressKeyPress = $true`

- Example from my Code

  ```
    $richTextBox1_KeyDown = {
        if($global:canType -eq $false) {
            if(!(@('Left','Up','Right','Down') -contains $_.KeyCode) -or ($_.KeyCode -eq 'Enter')) {
                $_.Handled = $true
                $_.SuppressKeyPress = $true
            }
        }
    }
  ```